# Dynamic allocation of array in C

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic, declaration, concept

It is always taught that arrays' size cannot be allocated during runtime in C. I ran a code to check this and my code works. I don't understand this. Why?

```
int n;
int a[n];      //here should be error, but its not//
scanf("%d", &n );
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
scanf("%d", &a[i] );
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
printf("%d", a[i] );
```

This should rise an error because size of array should be declared before compilation, but it does not.

Comment: If that's all the code you wrote, the result is undefined behavior; you haven't initialized `n` before declaring the array.

Comment: And that is a Variable Length Array (VLA), and it was added in the C99 version of the C language standard as an official part of the language, but later in C11 it was made to be only an optional feature, so not all compilers implement it (most notably MSVC doesn't have VLAs).